# ASP.NET WebForms Application onClick-Method

Tags: asp.net, webforms

The OnClick-Method of my WebForm don´t work.

**UI1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="UI1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6.UI1" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Formular zum bestimmen der Auftragsnummer</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">Rückmeldenummer:</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_rueck" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">Auftragsnummer:</asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Auftragsnummer bestimmen" OnClick="btn_getFAUF_Click" />
</fieldset>
</asp:Content>
```

**UI1.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public partial class UI1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btn_getFAUF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

> Kompilierungsfehler
>
> Beschreibung: Fehler bei der Kompilierung einer Ressource, die zur
>   Verarbeitung dieser Anforderung erforderlich ist. Überprüfen Sie die
>   folgenden spezifischen Fehlerdetails, und ändern Sie den Quellcode
>   entsprechend.
>
> Compilerfehlermeldung: CS1061: 'ASP.account_ui1_aspx' enthält keine
>   Definition für 'btn_getFAUF_Click', und es konnte keine
>   Erweiterungsmethode 'btn_getFAUF_Click' gefunden werden, die ein
>   erstes Argument vom Typ 'ASP.account_ui1_aspx' akzeptiert (Fehlt eine
>   Using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis?).
>
> Quellfehler:
>
> Zeile 15:                      Zeile 16:                 
>   Zeile 17:                  Zeile
>   18:              Zeile 19:
>
> Quelldatei: c:\Users\user.me\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WebApplication6\WebApplication6\Account\UI1.aspx
>   Zeile: 17

Comment: Try rebuilding your Application. If you added `btn_getFAUF_Click` without rebuilding it does not exist in the Library.

Comment: Oh that´s right, I am not used to .Net.

Comment: I bound a webservice to my Project and it created me automatically code, I can not build the project because of this: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161122/s93xncd7.png

Comment: Then you have to fix that error first. I don't know what is is since it's in German. If you're having trouble fixing it it's better to ask a new question (and translate the error messages).